# How to use modify-json-file with string value as key

Tags: node.js, json, npm

I am trying to modify a JSON file at runtime using the modify-json-file npm library but the generic API seems to work as follow

```
await modifyJsonFile(
    './filename',
    {
        name: "kevin"
    }
)
```

However, I wish to indicate the JSON key using a string variable, something like follow:

```
let key = "name";
await modifyJsonFile(
    './filename',
    {
        key: "kevin"
    }
)
```

How can I do that?

EDIT: any input is appreciated (e.g. if you think I should use the fs.writeFile instead), but I specifically look for solutions using the modify-json-file library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
{
    [key]: "New Value"
}
```

My json.

```
{
    "TimeAndUpdate": "oldValue"
}
```

The code:

```
const path = require('path');

const { modifyJsonFile } = require('modify-json-file');

const test = async () => {

    let key = "TimeAndUpdate";

    await modifyJsonFile(
        path.join(__dirname, "test.json"),
        {
            [key]: "New Value"
        }
    )
}

test();
```

Updated json:

```
{
    "TimeAndUpdate": "New Value"
}
```